# is it possible two foreign key from single primary key with different name with primarykey

Tags: database, postgresql

There are tables called `order` and `address`.

Column `address_id` is the `primary key` for the table `address`.

Columns `shipping_address_id` and `billing_address_id`, of table `order`, are `foreign keys` references the table `address`.

Is it correct or not?

Comment: Please show the table definitions, either as `CREATE TABLE` statements or output of `psql`'s `\d` command. I don't really understand what you're asking. If you're asking if the referenced column (PK) has to have the same name as the referencing column (FK), no, it doesn't.

Comment: just think there are only two tables first one is address and second one is order . In address table address_id is primary key. in order table forgeinkey name is shipping_address_id is this possible coz the name shol be same right?

Comment: There is *no requirement* that the names of the foreign key and the referenced unique or primary key column are the same. They can be different names.

Comment: Please do not use `order` as a table name. That's a reserved (key) word and will require you to use a quoted identifier - which will give you much more trouble in the long run that it's actually worth it.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    blah integer primary key
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    differentname integer references a(blah)
);
```

is perfectly valid. The referencing and referenced sides don't have to have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if *two* columns in one table can reference *one* column in another, then yes absolutely:

```
create table address
(
  address_id integer primary key
);

create table orders 
(
  id                   integer primary key,
  order_date           date not null, 
  shipping_address_id  integer references address,
  billing_address_id   integer references address
);
```

or more verbosely:

```
create table orders 
(
  id                    integer primary key,
  order_date            date not null, 
  shipping_address_id   integer,
  billing_address_id    integer,
  foreign key (shipping_address_id) references address (address_id),
  foreign key (billing_address_id) references address (address_id),
);
```